# How can I remember the last secltion/s and changes for EditorWindow?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : EditorWindow {
  [SerializeField] private GameObject prefab;
  [MenuItem("Tools/Test")]

  static void CreateTest() {
    EditorWindow.GetWindow<Test>();
  }

  private void OnInspectorUpdate() {
    Repaint();
  }
}
```

The script is in the Editor folder.
Then in the editor I select Tools > Test

The problem is that each time I add a prefab to the prefab variable when I close the EditorWindow and re open it again the prefab is gone/empty and I need to select the prefab again.

How can I make that it will remember the last selected prefab ? If the prefab still exist in the Assets but the idea is to remember the selected prefab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the value outside.
If you can find the prefab by name you can use PlayerPrefs class, or (harder but more versatile) serialize your own class to Json or other format.